# Avoid if/else in constructor - NavigableMap?

Tags: java

I have the following code, based on the input to the constructor I need to initialise some values which are wrapped in a simple POJO.. These values are constant as you can see.

However I don't like the if/else construct and had read about NavigableMap as an alternative for holding range values.. Any thoughts on how to improve/clean the below or indeed use this construct?

Thanks

```
private Calibrated calibratedValues;

public CalibrationProperties(long odNumber) {
    setCalibratedValues(odNumber);
}

private void setCalibratedValues(long odNumber) {
    if (odNumber < 762) {
        this.calibratedValues = new Calibrated(K0, H0, K0_INV, H0_INV, F0);
    } else if (odNumber < 866) {
        this.calibratedValues = new Calibrated(K1, H1, K0_INV, H0_INV, F1);
    } else if (odNumber < 1011) {
        this.calibratedValues = new Calibrated(K2, H2, K2_INV, H2_INV, F2);
    } else {
        this.calibratedValues = new Calibrated(K3, H3, K3_INV, H3_INV, F3);
    }

    //Two exceptions
    if (odNumber == 858){
        this.calibratedValues = new Calibrated(K2, H2, K2_INV, H2_INV, F2);
    }
    if (odNumber == 1005){
        this.calibratedValues = new Calibrated(K3, H3, K3_INV, H3_INV, F3);
    }
}

public Calibrated getCalibratedValues() {
    return calibratedValues;
}

/** Convenience class used to hold calibrated values */
static class Calibrated {
    private double[] k;
    private double[] h;
    private double[] kinv;
    private double[] hinv;
    private double f;

    Calibrated(double[] k, double[] h, double[] kinv, double[] hinv, double f) {
        this.k = k;
        this.h = h;
        this.kinv = kinv;
        this.hinv = hinv;
        this.f = f;
    }

    public double[] getK() {
        return k;
    }

    public double[] getH() {
        return h;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You should give the constants some meaningful names.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. Please try [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: You want the values to be assigned with some criteria and you don't want if..else condition???? or you don't want any conditional structure?? I don't exactly understand your question. 

But if you just don't want use if/else than you can use Switch case. only if you want some condition based structure...

Comment: There is a nice discussion here about if..else statements [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849656/design-pattern-to-implement-business-rules-with-hundreds-of-if-else-in-java), basically one of the best approaches seems to be a Strategy pattern..

Answer (score 0):

You are not using if/else in constructors here, but you have created something like factory method.

- use more meaningful names, if you will read this code after
  a year you will not know what they mean - I mean constructor parameters and class properties
- your constructor has too large argument list. You could create inside of your class some
  factory methods

Example:

```
public static Calibrated createSmallCaribration(){
   return new Calibrated(K0, H0, K0_INV, H0_INV, F0);
}
```

If you will do that you can even make your contructor package visible. And you will know what each constructor configuration is ment to be,

Comment: Is is more code review and discussion about clean code principals in practise:) But oyr could start with few changes mentioned above:)