# Best design pattern for "undo" feature

Tags: design-patterns, undo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design Pattern for Undo Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755/design-pattern-for-undo-engine)

In general, how do you deal with supporting an "undo" feature in your application? I have worked on web apps and desktop apps alike, and I have never really felt comfortable with any "undo" system I've made.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5168936/4629101) for implementing Undo/Redo.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe it should be [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design pattern.

Here is [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/UndoRedoPart2.aspx) about multilevel Undo/Redo with Command pattern.

EDIT: Here is [second](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/UndoRedoPart3.aspx) about multilevel Undo/Redo with Memento pattern.

So probably it can be done with both.

Answer (score 9):

Check out the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Answer (score 8):

I'd vote in favor of **Command pattern** over Memento. Memento pattern would be much costlier then Command patterns for Undo/Redo functionality.

> Capturing and Restoring object state
>   will be quite an expensive affair
>   compared to just doing or undoing an
>   action on any compatible object.