# Is it possible to use NSUndoManager without Core Data?

Tags: ios4, uigesturerecognizer, nsundomanager

I created an App without Core Data.
The App has a lots of functions such as manipulating views with gestures, colors and texts.

What I want to do is using the undo and redo functions.
I read everything about Core Data and NSUndoManager and I have problems to understand it, because everything I am trying to do...don't work.

My question is: is it possible to use NSUndoManager without Core Data?
And: how can I realize undos for the views?

One operation can change my Object called aView (UIImageView)
I register the information in the undoManager

**EDIT**

```
- (IBAction)rotationDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    static CGFloat initialRotation;
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        initialRotation = atan2f(gestureRecognizer.view.transform.b, gestureRecognizer.view.transform.a);
    }
    CGFloat newRotation = initialRotation + gestureRecognizer.rotation;
    aView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRotation);

    //undo
    [self.undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(rotationDetected:)object:aView];
    [self.undoManager setActionName:NSLocalizedString(@"viewChanged",@"title undo")];
}
```

And the undo Method which is called by a clicked Button is described here:

```
-(void)undo: (id) sender{ 

    [aView.undoManager undo];
    [[self undoManager] undo];
}
```

If I insert a if-clause asking if undoManager.canUndo == YES, it returns that undoManager can NOT undo. 
That means that the undoManager is nil, But why?
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `NSUndoManager` separately from Core Data. Plenty of info [out there](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/UndoManager.html) about NSUndoManager.

You need to do more reading and understand what `NSUndoManager` can and can't do for you and see how that would fit in with UIViews etc. Perhaps forget about Core Data for the moment and concentrate on `NSUndoManager`.

"because everything I am trying to do...don't work" -- if you're having specific problems you can ask questions here on StackOverflow about them. We can't help you with specifics if you only say "it doesn't work".

Outside of the specifics of `NSUndoManager`, there are design patterns related to undo and redo operations, for example the Command Pattern. See e.g. [Best design pattern for "undo" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448943/best-design-pattern-for-undo-feature).

Comment: Just code isn't enough either -- you need to say what you expected to happen, what happened. And there's a fine art to posting the correct snippet that allows the problem to be seen.

Comment: Have you put in NSLogs to see what is getting called and when?

Comment: therefore I do not understand it. I have everything written in my code, but it does not work. Did I miss something? Maybe in other classes such as in the appdelegate?