# Cancelling all changes and setting back to initially data through deep copy

Tags: c#, serializable, deep-copy

In my application I store all data in static list *AllData*, it inherited from;

```
public class GenericList<T> : BindingList<T>, IList<T>
```

I set user's changes to *AllData*'s selected item and my problem is about cancelling changes. If user cancels changes I retrieve all data from database again. This is not a useful solution; it takes time, creates new db connection etc.

I think that I already have old values before changes. I can backup first values and if user cancels changes, restore backed up values. Problem is coming here; I tried to clone *AllData*'s selected item through *ObjectCopier* class

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source)
```

, and got error like

> Type 'Class XYZ' is not marked as serializable.

Yes, I have several serialized classes and the others not serialized. The *AllData*'s selected item what I'm trying to clone, contains all data types what I created.

Should I seralize all classes? If yes; can this cause any problems (security, performance etc.)? or is there any useful method for cancelling operation?

Comment: If you are looking for a generalized `undo` function, have a look at Rockford Lhotka's CSLA framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448943/best-design-pattern-for-undo-feature