# Rollback an object properties to their initial state

Tags: c#, object, rollback

I have a grid that is displaying some data, each row corresponding to an object (Dataset being: `IEnumerable<Object> MyObject`). The user is able to update the data but would also like to give him the possibility to undo these changes.

I was going to code my own method saving first on the side any object that is modified by the user, ready to rollback to the original state if needed, but wondering if there is something already available in the .Net framework does that?

Comment: I [asked a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795692/cancelling-all-changes-and-setting-back-to-initially-data-through-deep-copy) a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

SO you might want to look into the [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) interface.

There is nothing built in(that i'm aware of) that will give you change tracking.

The example they have in that MSDN article is a pretty good one of how you could do it.