# How to implement undo and redo for drawText

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, drawtext

I've created a drawing app whereby the undo and redo functions are implemented (by adding or removing path). I'm able to undo or redo the strokes on my drawing. Subsequently, I added an "Add Text" feature using drawText. The Undo or Redo feature works only for my drawing. Is there a way to implement it for my Text as well?

Comment: There is no built-in undo for paths or anything else so you must have implemented that somehow. Just generalize the approach to work with text as well. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448943/best-design-pattern-for-undo-feature

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm still trying, but haven't met with any success so far.