# Undo operation for series in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, mschart

I want to restore previous series after changing some Yvalues[0] multiple times in the chart. So I have implemented undo operation using memento pattern.

But it's not working and there is no error while running. Below is the originator, memento and caretaker.

```
public class Originator
{

    private Series _series = new Series();

    public Originator(Series series)
    {
        _series = series;
    }
    public Series OSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return _series;
        }
        set
        {
            _series = value;
        }
    }

    public Memento SaveSeries()
    {
        return new Memento(_series);
    }

    public void RestoreSeries(Memento m)
    {
        this._series = m.MMseries;
    }
 }

public class Memento
{
    private Series _series =new Series();

    public Memento(Originator org)
    {
        this._series = org.OSeries;
    }
    public Memento(Series mseries)
    {
        _series = mseries;
    }

    public Series MMseries
    {
        get
        {
            return _series;
        }
        set
        {
            _series = value;
        }
    }
}
public class Caretaker
{
    //  private static Caretaker _instance;


    //  public Caretaker() { }

    private Memento chartMemento;
    public Memento Memento
    {
        get
        { return chartMemento; }

        set
        {  chartMemento = value; }

    }
}
```

Created objects in  public partial class Form1 : Form

```
Originator _org;
Caretaker taker = new Caretaker();
```

While loading the chart from a file, open_file function contains this code:

```
_org = new Originator(global_series); //For undo/redo operation
while (chart1.Series.Count > 0) { chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0); }

chart1.Series.Add(global_series);
taker.Memento = _org.SaveSeries();
```

For Undo_button:

```
_org.RestoreSeries(taker.Memento);
while (chart1.Series.Count > 0) { chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0); }
global_series = _org.OSeries;
chart1.Series.Add(global_series);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Series` is a **reference** variable.

Therefore all changes you make will be be to the series and all references you have will point to the same (original) series.

Fancy patterns, useful as they **might** be can't replace elementary knowledge. To allow **undo/redo** you need a **copy** of the **data**, not of the **reference**!

Note the `Series` doesn't have a `Clone` method.

So you need to do it yourself; in your case this boils down to **copying the Points**..

But for a more general case you would want to copy other series properties, most notable the `ChartType` but basically everyting you did to prepare the `Series`. Maybe create it in a factory pattern..?

**But** also note the `DataPoint` **does** have a `Clone` method. So you may change your `Originator` constructor like so:

```
public Originator(Series series)
{
    //_series = series;
    foreach (var dp in series.Points) _series.Points.Add(dp.Clone());
}
```

and things will start to work as expected. But you will need to do the restoring like this as well or else you would point to the saved series and the next changes would change it instead of the chart series..:

```
public void RestoreSeries(Memento m)
{
    // this._series = m.MMseries;
    this._series.Points.Clear();
    foreach (var dp in m.MMseries.Points) this._series.Points.Add(dp);
}
```

Btw: To clear all series use `chart.Series.Clear()` !

Comment: Thanks a lot , its working! Although for single undo operation. I'm sure this will give a start up to do multiple undo operations. Once I get solution, I will upload the code.

Comment: The usual solution for multiple do/undo operatins is a queue. Or is the pattern supposed to work for multiple undos? In that case I missed a bit..

Comment: Yes the pattern should work for multiple undos. Can this happen ?

Comment: Ah, ok the Memento makes the same mistake of just copying references.. But I think for multiple undos you need a `List<Originator.Memento>`, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) - Also see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448943/best-design-pattern-for-undo-feature)

Comment: I made 'List<Originator>' and 'List<Caretaker>'. Its working for multiple undo operations. The code is given below.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple undo operations using Memento Pattern

Code for Caretaker:

```
public class Caretaker
{

    private Memento chartMemento;
    public Memento Memento
    {
        get
        { return chartMemento; }

        set
        {  chartMemento = value; }

    }
}
```

Code for Memento:

```
public class Memento
{
    private Series _series =new Series();

    public Memento(Originator org)
    {
        this._series.Points.Clear();
        foreach (var dp in org.OSeries.Points) this._series.Points.Add(dp.Clone());
    }
    public Memento(Series mseries)
    {
        this._series.Points.Clear();
        foreach (var dp in mseries.Points) this._series.Points.Add(dp.Clone());
    }

    public Series MMseries
    {
        get
        {
            return _series;
        }
        set
        {
            _series = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for Originator

```
public class Originator{
    private Series _series = new Series();
    public Originator() { }
    public Originator(Series series)
    {
        // _series = series;
        _series.Points.Clear();
        foreach (var dp in series.Points) _series.Points.Add(dp.Clone());
    }
    public Series OSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return _series;
        }
        set
        {
            _series = value;
        }
    }

    public Memento SaveSeries()
    {
        return new Memento(_series);
    }

    public void RestoreSeries(Memento m)
    {
        //this._series = m.MMseries;

        this._series.Points.Clear();
        foreach (var dp in m.MMseries.Points) this._series.Points.Add(dp);
        this._series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    }
```

}

Declare list of objects and its counter in the Form1

```
 Orginator _org;
 List<Originator> list_org = new List<Originator>();
 List<Caretaker> list_taker = new List<Caretaker>();
 int obj_counter = 0;
```

Code for Do operations

```
 list_org.Add(_org = new Originator(global_series));
 Caretaker ct = new Caretaker();
 ct.Memento = list_org[obj_counter++].SaveSeries();
 list_taker.Add(ct);
```

Code for Undo operations:

```
  if (obj_counter > 0)
  {
     list_org[--obj_counter].RestoreSeries(list_taker[obj_counter].Memento);
     global_series.Points.Clear();
     foreach (var dp in list_org[obj_counter].OSeries.Points) 
     global_series.Points.Add(dp);
  }
```

Comment: If any improvement required for this code. Kindly let us know.

Comment: @TaW Thanks a lot for your suggestions.; these really saved my time.