# Updating path in paperjs and restoring previous state

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I am trying to use `paperjs` to create shapes. 
I also want to implement undo functionality, so when the shape is created I push it into a `undoList`

```
        const myCircle =  new Path.Ellipse({
            point: firstPoint,
            size: calculateSize(firstPoint, secondPoint)
        });
        this.undoList.push({
            name: myCircle.name,
            id: myCircle.id,
            type: "shape",
            object: myCircle
        });
```

Then I change the color of this created circle and again push to `undoList`.

```
        myCircle.strokeColor = "#ffffff;

        this.undoList.push({
            name: myCircle.name,
            id: myCircle.id,
            type: "shape",
            object: myCircle
        });
```

In my undo function, I am trying to delete the `item` using `item.remove().` This `item` is fetched using the `id` of `undoList`. After removing, I add the previous element of `undoList` if it has the same `id` (so that previous state is restored).

Now although I have changed the color, both the items in the `undoList` have the same color. So, there is no change visible. I think this is happening because they are both pointing to the same object.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are manipulating 2 references that simply point to the same object.

What you can do is the following:

- Every time you make a change to your `Item`, do an `Item.exportJSON()` and store the JSON in your undo list. This way you store the data of the `Item` as a `String`, instead of a reference.
- When you want to undo/redo just `.pop()` off your stack and do `myCircle.importJSON(json)`.

This is just one way to do it, but it's not really efficient in terms of memory consumption.

---

**Side note**: You might want to look into using the [Command Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448943/best-design-pattern-for-undo-feature) instead; The basic idea is that you store actions you take on your `Item`'s instead of snapshotting their whole data every time you undo/redo.