# Best way to undo previous steps in a series of steps

Tags: python, optimization, design-patterns, coding-style

I'm trying to find a better way to execute the following functions. I have a series of steps that need to be completed, and if any fail, I need to undo the previous step like so:

```
try:
    A = createA()
except:
    return None

try:
    B = createB(A)
except:
    deleteA(A)
    return None

try:
    C = createC(B)
except:
    deleteB(B)
    deleteA(A)
    return None

try:
    D = createD(C)
except:
    deleteC(C)
    deleteB(B)
    deleteA(A)
    return None

return D
```

I would prefer not to repeat myself if possible. How can I improve this? Is there a known pattern to follow?

One thing I have considered would be adding `deleteB(`) to `deleteC()`, and `deleteA()` to `deleteB()`. Is that the best possible way to do it?

Comment: One pattern to use could be the *context manager*, which you can `__enter__` and `__exit__` - you may have used this like `with open(...) as file_:`, for example, where it's used to close the file for you.

Comment: Since Python 3.3 there is `contextlib.ExitStack` in combination with context managers for such things.

Comment: One way to do is you could write an undo function that wraps around all your `deleteX()` functions and call it like `undo([C, B, A])`, where it parses your objs to delete and call `deleteX()` accordingly.  Though this is probably not the optimal approach.

Comment: I dont' know python but some equivalent to goto is actually a good solution this even though its frown upon. See [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+goto+chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources) for a general standard

Answer (score 0):

If you look some design patterns, check following:

[Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

It is probably what you are looking. Also, it commands can have "undo" action. Check the following question also, if it contains a similar problem that you have. [best design pattern for undo feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448943/best-design-pattern-for-undo-feature)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, this is what the context manager protocol is for. However, if you don't want to dig into what is a fairly advanced feature yet, then you can define `lambda` anonymous functions as you go, to remember what to tidy ...

```
try:
    deleters = []
    A = createA()
    deleters.append( lambda: deleteA(A) )
    B = createB( A)
    deleters.append( lambda: deleteB(B) )
    C = createC( B)
    deleters.append( lambda: deleteC(C) )
    D = createD( C)
    return D
except:
    for d in reversed( deleters):
        d()
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly "undo" means. E.g. if A, B, C, D etc are arbitrary user commands and there may be a large number of them in any order, then likely you need to write some sort of abstraction around do/undo.

If alternatively A, B, C, D etc are resources that need tidying up (database connections, files, etc), then context managers may be more appropriate.

Or maybe A, B, C D are some other sort of thing altogether.

A brief bit of code using context managers:

```
class A:
    def __enter__(self):
        set things up
        return thing
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        tear things down

class B, C and D are similar

def doSomethingThatNeedsToUseD():
    try:
        with A() as a:
        with B() as b:
        with C() as c:
        with D() as d:
            d.doSomething()
    except:
        print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called *memento pattern*. It is one of the GoF design patterns:

> Without violating encapsulation, capture and externalize an object's internal state so that the object can be restored to this state later.

The one way how it could be implemented using `python` could be find [here](https://gist.github.com/fabiobatalha/5404977).