# I need a design pattern to provide undo functionality to my program

Tags: design-patterns, memento

I need a design pattern to provide undo functionality to my program. I've already used Memento, but I need another for my coursework.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755/design-pattern-for-undo-engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is the classic pattern for an undo model.

basically encapsulate each action in an object (the command) and then make each command able to perform the reverse action.  Keep a list of the commands as they are applied and to undo perform the reverse action on the list in reverse.

an example of using the command pattern for undo is [here](http://mattberther.com/2004/09/16/using-the-command-pattern-for-undo-functionality), although that was simply the first result from a [google of 'command pattern for undo'](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=command+pattern#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=command+pattern+for+undo&aq=f&aqi=g-v1g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=5640bd756f22a93a)