# how to implement undo operation in painting app

Tags: iphone

I am doing a painting app. In that, I draw some image. But I want to add undo operation to remove the previous drawn item. How can I implement that undo operation?

Comment: How do you store the objects that have been drawn? The answer highly depends on your code. Core Data has a nice undo/redo mechanism.

Comment: i added one button for saving that drawn image. so, when i hit save button, then its stored into core data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an application named TouchPainter and its source code is available. It contains drawing, color blending, Undo/Redo (Amazing..!!), Save/Open drawings..

Note : It may require very deep level knowledge of Objective C. The whole application's source code is explained in this book "Apress.Pro.Objective-C.Design.Patterns.for.iOS.Mar.2010" available and source code is also available here :

http://www.apress.com/apple-mac/objective-c/9781430233305

I hope it will be helpful to you.. :) Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link:
[Design Pattern for Undo Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755/design-pattern-for-undo-engine)

Generally speaking, you need to implement a Command Pattern(or a similar one). 
If one operation can be reversed,(for example, in graphics program, you scale up a circle), you can store the modification in the command.
else, you might have to save a deep clone of the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an NSMutableArray adding each operation on it.

```
NSMutableArray *ObjectList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[ObjectList addObject: TheSKSprite1];
[ObjectList addObject: TheSKSprite2];
[ObjectList addObject: TheSKSprite3];
...
```

then retrieve the last Drawing added, to removed it from the View and from the Array.

```
SKSpriteNode *OneDrawing = [ObjectList objectAtIndex:(int)[ObjectList count]-1];
[OneDrawing removeFromParent];
[ObjectList removeObjectAtIndex:(int)[ObjectList count]-1];
```

I hope it could helps you.