# Use of Java Stack to detect order of method calls

Tags: java, stack, queue

Java beginner, who would appreciate feedback on how best to approach a problem which I'm working on in isolation.....

Trying to build a basic game, where a player moves around a grid/board. Have up/down/left/right methods (e.g. public void playerMovesUp() etc), and need to implement undo/redo move functionality, so a player can retrace x number of steps, and then retake x number at any point during game play.

Have been looking into ways to do this i.e. to record the order of the up/down/left/right method calls, and then re-call both in reverse order (undo) and then redo.

A stack, or queue collection seems logical....and I have also looked into the java stack memory storing the order of function calls, and have just read about java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace().

Current thoughts.....If I isolate those four methods into one thread, then I could use java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace() to return an array, and call getMethodName(), to then somehow call applicable methods in order?

Also, is it possible to store a queue/stack of method calls?

I feel like I'm on the right path, but the last suggestion seems a bit messy/illogical! Any pointers/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Java `Stack` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: usually, one would design the actions in different Classes using the Command-Pattern to implement undo.  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755/design-pattern-for-undo-engine)

Comment: Store your movements in a `Stack` i.e. "right" "left" "up" "down"...then when you want to traverse backwards just grab the top element of the `Stack` and do the opposite. `if(topElement.equalsIgnoreCase("right")){moveLeft();}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot use the Stack for this. You have to keep track of your method calls yourself. And no, you cannot store "method calls" into a Collection.

Instead, it would be easier to design classes for your actions, where each class implements a `do` and a `undo`. The instances of these classes can then be stored in a `Stack` or `Queue`. If the user wants to undo his actions, you can process it backwards and calling undo on all elements. This pattern is known as the Command Pattern (see eg.g. [Design Pattern for Undo Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755/design-pattern-for-undo-engine))

Comment: Thanks Raphael. If I created a new class for each action (up/down etc), and it generates an object each time the player moves one grid space, wouldn't it be a lot more inefficient than say, just adding a string each time the player moves to my stack? So I have a stack of "left", "up", "right", "up" etc. Otherwise I could end up with a vast amount of objects in my stack as there are no limitations on the number of times a player can move. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the stack like that. That's not what this if for.
Just keep a list of steps you took and retrace your steps using that list.